# Who are the top 3 actresses based on number of Super Hit movies (average rating >8) in drama genre using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 SELECT n.name as actress_name , r.total_votes , COUNT(r.movie_id) as movie_count, r.avg_rating as actress_avg_rating, 
    RANK() OVER( 
                ORDER BY 
                COUNT(r.movie_id) DESC
                ) actress_rank
    FROM names as n
    INNER JOIN role_mapping as rm
    ON n.id = rm.name_id
    INNER JOIN movie as m
    ON rm.name_id = m.id
    INNER JOIN ratings as r
    ON m.id = r.movie_id
    INNER JOIN genre as g
    ON g.movie_id = r.movie_id
    WHERE r.avg_rating > 8 AND g.genre = 'Drama' AND rm.category ='actress'
    GROUP BY actress_name
    LIMIT 3;
```

Please help me with this! I am also confused if it is the average of 'avg_rating' column for a actress.
[image: ERD]

Comment: Please post any errors or describe/show undesired results. By default settings of MySQL 8, this code should error out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, properly run an aggregate query. MySQL due to the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting turned off [permits non-aggregated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) to be omitted in `GROUP BY` clause which in proper ANSI SQL should error out unless omitted column(s) is functionally dependent on columns in `GROUP BY`.

Secondly, calculate needed `RANK()` partitioned on `actress_name` using the `movie_count` aggregate. And in outermost query, subset by calculaetd rank column. With CTEs, you can refactor code by these steps:

```sql
WITH agg (
  SELECT n.name AS actress_name
         , SUM(r.total_votes) AS total_votes        -- TURNED AGGREGATE
         , AVG(r.avg_rating)  AS movie_avg_rating   -- TURNED AGGREGATE (RENAMED ALIAS)
         , COUNT(r.movie_id)  AS movie_count
         , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY n.name          -- ADDED PARTITION
                       ORDER BY COUNT(r.movie_id) DESC) AS actress_rank
  FROM names as n
  INNER JOIN role_mapping as rm
      ON n.id = rm.name_id
  INNER JOIN movie as m
      ON rm.name_id = m.id
      AND rm.category ='actress'
  INNER JOIN ratings as r
      ON m.id = r.movie_id
      AND r.avg_rating > 8 
  INNER JOIN genre as g
      ON g.movie_id = r.movie_id
      AND g.genre = 'Drama' 
  GROUP BY n.name
)

SELECT actress_name
       , total_votes
       , movie_avg_rating
       , movie_count
       , actress_rank
FROM agg
WHERE actress_rank <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need **aggregations** , and **partitioning** within the `RANK()` analytic function, while removing `LIMIT` clause such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT n.name AS actress_name , 
          AVG(r.avg_rating) AS actress_avg_rating, 
          SUM(r.total_votes) AS total_votes,
          COUNT(r.movie_id) AS movie_count, 
          RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY n.name 
                            ORDER BY COUNT(r.movie_id) DESC) AS actress_rank      
     FROM names AS n
     JOIN role_mapping AS rm
      ON n.id = rm.name_id
     JOIN movie AS m
      ON rm.name_id = m.id
     JOIN ratings AS r
      ON m.id = r.movie_id
     JOIN genre AS g
      ON g.movie_id = r.movie_id
    WHERE r.avg_rating > 8 AND g.genre = 'Drama' AND rm.category ='actress'
    GROUP BY actress_name  
  ) q
 WHERE actress_rank <= 3
```